# How do you enable antialiasing in a Gtk::GLArea?

Tags: c++, opengl, antialiasing, gtkmm

I'm doing some OpenGL within a Gtk::GLArea and I'd like to enable MULTISAMPLING antialiasing.

The [docs](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Multisampling#Rendering_with_Multisampling) say:

> There are two pieces to rendering with multisampling:
>
> - Allocating a multisample render target (window or FBO), and
> - Enabling multisample rasterization (i.e. glEnable( GL_MULTISAMPLE ))
>
> While the second step is standardized across all render target types and platforms, the first is only standardized for FBOs (as it is totally internal to GL). When rendering to a window, the allocation method depends on the platform-specific GL integration layer in-use (e.g. WGL, GLX, AGL, etc.). GLUT provides a wrapper around some of these so you don't have to care.
>
> The following sections describe how to perform MSAA render target allocation (#1) for various render target types and platforms.

I have done part 2.  How do I do part 1?  Some pseudocode to illustrate where I am:

```
#include <gtkmm/application.h>

void on_realize() {
  gl_area.make_current();
  if (GLenum res = glewInit(); res != GLEW_OK) {
    std::cerr << glewGetErrorString(res) << std::endl;
    exit(1);
  }
}

bool on_render(const Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::GLContext>& /*context*/) {
  glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE_ARB);  // I've tried GL_MULTISAMPLE as well.
  // Draw
}

main() {
  Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Application> app = Gtk::Application::create();
  Gtk::Window window;
  Gtk::GLArea gl_area;
  gl_area.signal_realize().connect(&on_realize);
  gl_area.signal_render().connect(&on_render);
  window.add(gl_area);
  gl_area.show();
  app->run(window);
}
```

I was expecting there to be a Gtk::GLArea::set_enable_multisampling(bool) that I could call from on_realize.  I've checked Gtk::Window and Gdk::GLContext.  Neither seem to be antialiasing-aware.